# Модуль для информационного сайта

Tags: php, архитектура

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне концепцию модуля. Нужно сделать модуль поиска маршрутов автобусов. Есть поле отправление и точка назначение. При вводе в поле при наборе первых букв выводятся все возможные города. При помощи чего можно сделать эту фичу?

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

Таблица маршрутов: id, номер num, название name etc

Таблица остановок: id, маршрут mid, название name, город city [, координаты x/y] etc

Ну и соответственно по запросу ищем маршрут, в котором есть начальная и конечная точка, что-то вроде

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM marshrut as m
  JOIN points as p1 ON p1.mid = m.id
  JOIN points as p2 ON p2.mid = m.id
WHERE
  p1.city = 'Moscow' AND
  p2.city = 'NewYork'
;
```

Выбор города по первым буквам - банальщина, гуглите) Да хотя бы алгоритм подсказок гугла гуглите))

```
// Спойлер: ... WHERE city LIKE 'Mos%';
```

Comment: Большое спасибо... Ну я в принципе подозревал, что так и надо. Вся таблица маршрутов в excel книге (листы: пригород, межгород и т.д.). ее считать можно компонентой phpexcel в Mysql базу походу )))